# Align navigation bar with main body of text

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to align the left-most element of my navigation bar with the main body of text below it. I currently have that but it's a "dirty" solution and pushes the navigation out of view on mobile.

[image: How it should look]

Here's how I want it to look. My current way of doing this is below:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

/* nav structure */

#header {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#menu-nav {
    padding: 15px 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    left: 660px;
}

#menu-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu-nav li a {
    padding: 15px 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

As you can see I use a left value of 660px which really pushes the navigation over. Is there a way I can align it so that it looks like this on mobile too? Here's the current mobile view:

[image: Mobile View]

If you need to view the actual site: http://adamshort.site50.net

Comment: Just give #menu-nav a width and auto margins like you have done for #wrapper and #main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to `ul#menu-nav`

```
#menu-nav {
padding: 15px 0px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help you if your HTML code was provided as well, and unfortunately I am unable to get your website to load.

However, I would suggest changing your #wrapper to be a class, then you could wrap your navigation content with the same wrapper that you are applying to your content.  This way they would both respect the same (responsive) left margin. Then simply left aligning your navigation list would cause it to begin at the same point as the content below it.

The way you are approaching it is not responsive and only works on pages of a certain width, as you explicitly telling the Nav to sit 660px from the left side of the page always.  Meanwhile your content wrapper has a **margin: 0 auto** which causes margin from the left of the page to dynamically change based upon the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
.menu-nav-container {
  text-align: center;
}

#menu-nav {
  padding: 15px 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Just shifts the navigation over to the very left edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its within #wrapper you can just give it a width and center it like you have #main:

```
#menu-nav { 
padding: 0px; 
position: relative; 
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```